# My mom wants me to divorce my wife because she is too short; what should I do?

Tags: nikah

I am newly married, and I am in abroad now. I really love my wife a lot, but my mom is asking me to divorce her; she says my wife is too short.  My parents themselves selected a girl for me. I don't have any problem with my wife, specially with height issue.

My father does not know this issue, otherwise he would be very angry with my mother for sure.  Kindly help me what decision shall I take, because my mother is pressurising me a lot. I am also afraid If I don't follow my mother, Allah will be angry with me.

Comment: Your mother's rights end where your wife's rights start. Divorce is the most hated of permissible things in the sight of Allah [(hadith)](https://sunnah.com/urn/1263370) You are breaking your home and destroying her life just because she is short? You fear Allah for being angry with you for ignoring your mother's absurd demands, yet you can't think that your wife's cry will reach Him because she was judged for how Allah created her?

Comment: Also [لاَ طَاعَةَ فِي مَعْصِيَةٍ، إِنَّمَا الطَّاعَةُ فِي الْمَعْرُوفِ](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/95/12) There is no obedience for evil deeds, obedience is only in what is good.

Comment: Don't do this man. As you said "my parents themselves selected girl for me". She should have thought his before tie you in marriage relationship. And now this will be very very bad decision if you do that(if follow your mom order.)